# Getting compilation errors when trying to add QR code scanner to a Qt project

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt

I'm trying to add a QR code scanner to my `iOS` project written using `Qt Quick`.

I've found [this example](https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReaderViewController) on how to achieve it using native APIs.

I've added QRCodeReaderViewController/* files to my project and trying to build it. Getting weird compilation errors. I suspect some Xcode build settings are required to be enabled, but I don't know how to do it using `qmake`.

```
../ios/QRCodeReaderViewController/QRCodeReaderViewController.m:46:1: error: cannot synthesize weak property in file using manual reference counting
    @implementation QRCodeReaderViewController

../ios/QRCodeReaderViewController/QRCodeReaderViewController.m:107:5: error: cannot create __weak reference in file using manual reference counting
    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information for us to be able to help you. You should probably create a minimal reproducible example, upload it to GitHub, and add a link in your question. (I've never heard of Qt Quick or QML, so I've got nothing to draw from to help you. I googled Qt Quick but it sounds like a pretty complex framework.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW15) (unfortunately it's in "Documentation Archive", but I hope it still works), you can try this in your **.pro** file:

```
ios {
    QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS += -fobjc-arc
}
```

If this doesn't work, you may also try to set `QMAKE_IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to something like `11.0` or higher, because there might be [issues](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725300) with newer compiler versions.